# How do I make Design Templates like Canva Templates that are unique but can be modified & exported as an image? Should I use Canvas or WebGL?

Tags: web-development, canvas, webgl

Canva has [Templates](https://www.canva.com/templates/) that are unique & can be easily modified by anyone & replaced with their own text, images, etc...

I want to build something like that.

I have multiple options to use but don't know which one is good or which one is fast enough to code.

My options are:

1. DOM with [html-to-image](https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image) for screenshot
2. Canvas
3. [Konva](https://konvajs.org/) or React Konva
4. [Tldraw](https://www.tldraw.com/)
5. [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/)
6. WebGL

I have used Canvas & Konva but never used the others. I don't even know what WebGL is but all the biggies like Figma & Veed use it for their editors.

My focus is on building multiple unique templates at speed.

I found Konva annoying because I had to do a lot of math even for simple stuff like padding & it throws error on negative numbers on x, y co-ordinates.

Canvas feels pretty vanilla. Using that means I have to re-create my own framework on top of that. It is hard as I had tried creating one years ago with JavaScript.

What would you use? I am looking for speed of execution & a modular framework.

Also, how would you create it? Will it have to be like Webflow where it's all drag-n-drop? Or custom made components written with code? What's the best way?

Comment: The format of this community requires each post only ask one question at a time. Currently, this post asks multiple questions. Can you edit your question to focus on a single problem? Keep in mind that tool recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @GregBurghardt this is 1 question only. i am not asking for tool recommendations either. i am asking how do i approach solving this problem of creating templates. i have laid out all possible ways i can go to but i am having a hard-time on which one to choose.